# Meta keyword not show on home page in WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, seo

I would like to enter meta keywords of the home page. My website running with WordPress 4.4.2 and I have used yoast seo plugin latest version.
I have try to enter the same on Home page through same plugin but still not work. Website Url: [www.educationandcareer.org](http://www.educationandcareer.org)

I found meta tag on page source like -

```
<meta name="description" content="A website for online mock test,study materials for competitive exam, recruitment news, government orders, question papers and more."/>
<meta name="robots" content="noodp,noydir"/>
<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="87BBBED004E2382F2F5806948E50E0FE" />
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="BG4WnUCk4rZfEiGS2Cx4I17qUhJbWdHTJ9yvapKy-_M" />
<meta name="p:domain_verify" content="a65b3d1d58dca2acbef5b749b5329e38" />
```

All other meta tag working fine.

Please anyone give me any idea or solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, 
1.Go to your wordpress dashboard, SEO ( I mean yoast plugin menu ) 
2. In Yoast menu, Enter "**Title and metas**" where you see General , Homepage, Post Types etc. 
3. Here Click on the last option "**Other**". 
4. You see it ? Check The Box "**Use meta keywords tag?**" 
5. Save Changes.

But As far as I know, Meta keywords are not being used by any major search engines and No Big Brothers are using it.